# integration increasing decreasing

Tags: integration

Let f be a continuous strictly increasing function from $[0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ and $g=f^-1$ (i.e.$f(x)=y \iff g(y)=x$). Let $a,b>0$ and $a\neq b$.Then $ \int\limits_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$+$\int\limits_{0}^{b}g(y)dy$ is

(A) greater than or equal to ab

(B) less than ab

(C) always equal to ab

Comment: what you could not read. Can you tell how to write infinity

Comment: I think you want $f(a)\neq b.$ If $f(a)=b$ then the value is exactly $ab.$

Comment: You have taken the same title as your previous question : it is not at all adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the function $f^{-1}(x)$ is a reflection of the function $f(x)$ about the line $y=x$. If we look at the integral of the inverse first:
$$I_1=\int_0^bf^{-1}(x)dx$$
$x=f(y)$, $dx=f'(y)dy$ and so:
$$I_1=\int_0^{f(b)}yf'(y)dy$$
and since you said $f$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$ we can say $f'(y)>0$ and so clearly $I_1>0$. If we do IBP we get:
$$I_1=\left[yf(y)\right]_{y=0}^{f(b)}-\int_0^{f(b)} f(y)dy$$

---

Now if we look at $f$:
$$I_2=\int_0^af(x)dx$$
this is the best we can simplify for a general equation, and so:
$$I_1+I_2=\left[yf(y)\right]_{y=0}^{f(b)}+\int_{f(b)}^af(x)dx$$
$$=f(b)f(f(b))+\int_{f(b)}^a f(x)dx$$
Now what can we say about this statement, well clearly for $a>f(b)$ and if $f(x)>0$ for $(0,\infty)$ then:
$$I_1+I_2\ge f(b)f(f(b))+(a-f(b))f(b)$$

Answer (score -2):

Since you have only three choices, try some simple examples.

The very simplest is to take f(x)= x, a= b= 1.  Then g(x)= x and $\int_0^1 xdx+ \int_0^1 xdx= 2(x^2/2)_0^1= 1$.  That is equal to ab= 1 so we can drop "< ab" but not  "$\ge ab$".

To distinguish between those, try $f(x)= x^2$, a= b= 1.  Then $g(x)= x^{1/2}$ and $\int_0^1 x^2dx+ \int_0^1 x^{1/2}dx= \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{2}{3}= \frac{5}{3}$. That is strictly greatere that ab= 1 so  we must say "$\ge ab$".

Comment: $a\neq b$ is part of the condition.

Comment: It is a way to answer to a test, but the general case is not more complicated (see the reference I have given).

Comment: Also, $\frac13 +\frac23=1,$ not $\frac53.$